# How to define the rotation for a collection of connected objects

Tags: math, physics

I have a number of objects, each with their own rotation and location. Their rotations are defined as quaternions, and their location as a 3 dimensional vector.
The collection of objects together behaves like a single rigidbody. 
Objects can be created and destroyed.

The collection of objects, lets call it an "Assembly" (like, assembly of parts) has a defined position, as the center of mass of all the objects. (Really just a weighted average of all of the objects positions). This position changes in response to new objects being added and removed, and changes in responce to all of the objects moving as a whole.

How would you define a rotation for the Assembly in the same way? 
ie: a quaternion representation for the entire collection of objects
-the rotation of the assembly would represent the rotation of the objects as a whole. Adding or removing objects would *not* change the assemblies rotation, because the rotation is defined independently of position.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define **orientation**, or a **rotation operator**?

Comment: I would do it the same way skeletons work. Quaternions and seeing it as a chain of transformations (rotations): part_rotation_quaternion * assembly_rotation_quaternion

Comment: orientation, If I understand the term correctly. For example: a cube with a rotation of 38 degrees in 2d space.

Comment: The assembly has some rotation relative to the "world". Each part of the assembly has a rotation relative to the assembly. To compute the rotation of the part relative to world, you need to consider both.

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler angles and principal axes?

Comment: Euler angles have the problem of having error prone "singularities" at certain angles. Quaternions do not have that problem. This is why e.g. in robotics but also in other 3D applications quaternions are prefered most of the time. See for example http://www.3dkingdoms.com/weekly/weekly.php?a=4 for an introduction.

Comment: Euler angles somewhat yes, I'm not sure about principal axes, unless I'm just unfamiliar with that particular name.

Comment: user2225104, yes, that's why I am using quaternions to store the orientation.

Comment: Regarding principal axis. Wikipedia explains them using 3x3 matrices. In 3d programming, most people use 4x4 matrices for that. Maybe someone else can elaborate on that.

Comment: Ok, I definitely don't understand principal axis, though am trying to via the Wikipedia article. I take it understanding this concept would help with the solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't think they help solve your problem with your "body hierarchy". Your center of mass approach along with treating the parts relative to the assembly "reference point", aka your center of mass should be sufficient.

Comment: Judging by your edit, I'd say you've chosen to go with quaternions. So what more do you need?

Comment: OK I think I figured it out. Basically the assembly keeps track of the rotation of the last objects rotation, and changes its rotation based on that. Its really complicated keeping track of it though. Should I post this as the answer?